# Post Error when submitting Angular form data to Azure SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-appservice

I have a fully working ASP.NET Angular website that saves a form data to a database. I have managed to deploy it to Azure App Service and also connected to Azure SQL Database using visual studio. However when I save the form I have a post error. This is my first time, is there anything else that I need to do in order for the form to work because initially it was working with my local database?.

This is a screenshot of the error

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I am creating an Azure SQL database and inserting data from asp.net. Connection_time_out error comes when the application is not connected to the server.

Create Azure SQL Database and create the table.

[image]

C# code for insert data into Azure Sql Database.

```cs
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            //Connection String  
            string cs = "Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=punitdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
            SqlConnection con;
            SqlDataAdapter adapt;
            DataTable dt;
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd;
            string s = "insert into Persons values(@PersonID,@LastName,@FirstName,@email,@message)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "Kumar");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "Roshan");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "Roshan@gmail.com");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", "Hello Roshan");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Any key for Show data ");


            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 1 * from Persons order by PersonID desc", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);

            Console.WriteLine("First Name :-" + dt.Rows[0][2] + ", Last Name :-" + dt.Rows[0][1] + ", Emamil :-" + dt.Rows[0][3] + ", Message :- " + dt.Rows[0][4]);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

code output
[image]

After running code
[image]

Microsoft document on [Connection timeout expired errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql#connection-timeout-expired-errors)

Read this Microsoft document for Common connection issue [steps to fix common connection issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql#steps-to-fix-common-connection-issues)